# Is self assigning safe in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grammar

This question has confused me these days: what happens when a variable is assigned to itself in Python? For example,

```
a = a if (a>b) else b
```

I know very little about the reference counting mechanism and get no idea about this question. Help me if you know the answer, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's safe. Nothing wrong in assigning a variable to it self.

Comment: why do you think it's unsafe?

Comment: Sidenote: your code can also be rewritten as `a = max(a, b)`

Comment: ok, thx dudes. Perhaps I just think too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfectly safe. Python will sequence everything after the `=` sign so the expression is computed before assigning the variable. <strike>I don't think there are any programming language where this wouldn't have been safe</strike> (see @hadik's comment below).

---

> what happens to the reference counts of that variable when self assigning?

In short, it'll do the right thing.

In a longer answer, to answer this question it's best to look at the disassembly, by running this code:

```
import dis                   
def f(a, b): 
    a = a if (a>b) else b                                               
dis.dis(f)
```

Annotated disassembly:

```
      # the objects pointed by `a` and `b` starts with a positive refcount as they're part of the function argument

      # increment refcount for the object pointed by `a` and `b`
      0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
      2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)

      # COMPARE_OP (usually) returns boolean True/False
      # increment the refcount of the boolean value
      # and decrement the refcount of the object pointed by `a` and `b`
      4 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)

      # decrements the refcount of that boolean value
      6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12

      # increment refcount for the object pointed by `a`
      8 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)

     10 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 14)

      # increment refcount for the object pointed by `b`
>>   12 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)

      # decrement refcount for the object originally pointed by `a`
>>   14 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

     16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
     18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Some background info: Python VM is a stack machine. LOAD_* operation pushes a value to the stack (and increments its refcount as the stack now has a reference to the object), and most other operations will pop values from the stack and push the computed result to the stack (decrementing the refcount of the consumed values and incrementing the result). STORE_* operation moves an object from the top of the stack to the variable (and decrementing the refcount of the original object referred by the variable; it does not need to change the refcount of the object being moved, as popping off the stack and setting to a variable effectively doesn't change the refcount).

In short, Python refcount always do the right thing even when multithreaded (that's thanks to GIL). You really should never need to worry about the refcount, if an object is reachable from a scope, it will not be garbage collected.

Comment: There can be issues with self-assignment with objects. For example, with `Eigen::Matrix` in `c++`, if you do `a = a.transpose()`, it would not work due to aliasing. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is very useful to me. My another question is: what happens to the reference counts of that variable when self assigning? I've heard that in Python the assignment actually copies the reference. Does the count number simply remain the same or +1 first and then -1 to the initial value?

Comment: @Goyo, Lie Ryan wrote : `I don't think there are any programming language where this wouldn't have been safe.`, so it is response to that

Comment: @Bobholamovic: Python variables don't have reference count, it's objects that have reference counts. I've expanded my answer to  your other question as it's a bit complicated to explain in a comment.

Comment: @hadik: Thanks for that info. Very useful to watch out on C++.

Comment: @LieRyan Understood. Thanks a lot!